# Pass properties to recursive templates?

Tags: reactjs

Is there a more elegant solution than re-passing all the properties again when using recursive templates?

```
<!-- CommentList.js -->
<Comment comment="comment" property="one" property="two"></Comment>

<!-- Comment.js -->
<p>{comment.message}</p>

<!-- loop over comment.children (more comments, same properties) -->
    <Comment comment="comment" property="one" property="two"></Comment>
<!-- end loop -->
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand ... are you trying to transfer all props to children? http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html

Comment: I'm trying to re-pass the same properties within recursive templates (Comment includes Comment with all the necessary properties coming from the parent CommentList) --> Updated question

Comment: Would `<Comment {...this.props} />` do what you want as suggested in the link I provided?

Comment: Ah, that's what they mean by "spreading properties". Indeed. You can post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to transfer the properties you can use [JSX spread attributes](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html) to inject the properties of the parent control into a specified element:

The syntax is similar to a syntax in EcmaScript 6 (and something proposed in 7): `{...props}`.

By using `this.props` for example, you'll get all of the properties of the parent class copied into the child. (It could be `{...myObj}` as well ... it will copy values from the object named `myObj` in that example.)

So, in your example, it might be:

```
return <Comment {...this.props} extra="stuff" />;
```

[Here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html) are more details and a few other options you could consider as well.